# What is the best way to write a large number of variables to a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a need to write a large number of variables to a MySQL database, using PHP. There is structure to the variable names, based around the letters a to z, hence the example below.

Currently the data is stored in a few variables ($title[LETTER], $unit[LETTER], $describe[LETTER]) so I'm sure/hoping there must be an easy way to loop through them.

How can I write this MySQL query without having to manually write 78 phrases? Is there a way to insert a loop in the MySQL call, or should I perhaps use a loop before this call?

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (a, a_unit, a_describe, b)
     VALUES ('$title[a]', '$unit[a]', '$describe[a]', '$title[b]')";
```

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)?

Comment: No, I am not. That is to prevent against a MySQL injection attack?

Comment: Are you referring to this sort of code?
    $title[$letr]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST[$letr]);

Comment: I'm referring to the fact that you're using string interpolation to introduce data into your queries, something that's been shown time and time again to be a bad idea, especially without escaping. Really [bad things happen](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you fail to do this properly. A guide like [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain in more detail why this is dangerous.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. If you use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will likely miss a few cases and create a horrendously bad injection hole.

Comment: I was (apparently erroneously) under the impression that the my_sqli_real_escape_string function was adequate to prevent this. Thank you so much for the advice and the links.

Comment: While it is possible to do that by calling escaping function manually, this is far more verbose than doing it with placeholder values. The escape function is provided for those relatively rare situations where placeholders won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you know all of the possible combinations of the letters you could build an array of them first.

```
$letters = array('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Then loop through that array and run the SQL

```
foreach($letters as $key => $letter) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO Persons ($letter, $letter_unit, $letter_describe) 
        VALUES ('$title[$letter]', '$unit[$letter]', '$describe[$letter]')";
};
```

That is running the SQL each time.

Comment: Should I be concerned about the time taken to complete either the multiple requests, or the one large single requests? I could always limit the multiple requests to the necessary ones, but I'm not sure if it's needed.

Comment: You should keep it in mind - that could be a lot of individual queries but depending on your structure you may not have other choices.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a loop before your SQL statement. What you can do is use a loop to build the string that will go inside your "values" section of your SQL statement then concatenate to your SQL statement then execute

Answer (score 0):

The best way: Write a script that will generate very long SQL automatically :)

And IMHO is better to use the format SET field = 'value', field2 = 'value' ... in the future will be easier to find the field and edit it if necessary

Comment: Does that format by any chance allow for looping within the query (or similar)?

Comment: The `SET` method isn't more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should build the query using a loop to construct it (to build the proper string)

```
INSERT INTO Persons(a, a_unit, a_describe, b)
VALUES('sth11', 'sth12', 'sth13', 'sth14'),
VALUES('sth21', 'sth22', 'sth23', 'sth24'),
...
VALUES('sthn1', 'sthn2', 'sthn3', 'sthn4')
```

you should make a for loop, which I'll write in pseudocode because, frankly, I don't know PHP. I'm sure you'll be able to follow the below idea in PHP:

```
query = 'INSERT INTO Persons (a, a_unit, a_describe, b) '
for letter in letters_to_loop_over:
    query += 'VALUES( ' + $title[letter] + ', ' + $unit[letter] + ', ' + $describe[letter] + ', ' + $title[letter] + '), '
```

then check if the string you've build looks like proper SQL (I'd just print it), and pass it as the query to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PDO to build your query before you commit it or do it manually as you suggested. However i see that the structure of your variables is not consistent ie. $title, $unit, etc. You should map all of the Person data to a class (Person.php), then your looping operations would be more fluid.

So basically you need a map of sorts like : Class::Person->a_describe = $describe['a']

Comment: I didn't even think of using a class... Time to do some reading!
Thanks.